# Google AppEngine App Version

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to fetch the current application version programmatically for use in urls with far future expires header?

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.js?v=1.23" />
```

Should be automatically updated to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.js?v=1.24" />
```

In order to do so I need to get the version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/theenvironment.html][1]

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import os

class PrintEnvironmentHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    for name in os.environ.keys():
      self.response.out.write("%s = %s<br />\n" % (name, os.environ[name]))


  [1]: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/theenvironment.html
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have been looking all over the appengine site and have been unable to find this for some reason.